# React native layout not changing as expected after rotation orientation change on iOS

Tags: react-native

When I start a new React Native project on a Mac with the latest versions XCode and React Native as follows:

```
react-native init TestApp
cd TestApp
react-native run-iso
react-native --version
react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.32.0
```

the app launches correctly in the iOS simulator in portrait and looks as expected.

[image: New React Native App Display]

However, when rotating the orientation by selecting from the menu Hardware --> Rotate Left the text is no longer centered and is cut off.

[image: New React Native App With Other Display]

I have tried a few other tests with flexbox and see similar behavior when rotating on iOS.  I also tried resetting the iOS emulator contents and settings using Simulator --> Reset Contents and Settings but I still see the same issue.

I launched a new app using the same procedure on Mac for iOS on another machine running the previous version of React Native (0.31) and it works as expected and responds normally when the orientation is changed.

In both, 0.32 and 0.31 everything displays correctly on an Android app running in the simulator.

[image: React App on Android in Other Orientation]

I am unclear if this is a misconfiguration on my desktop or if there is an issue in React Native 0.32.

Comment: You are not alone. I had the same problems and rolled back to version 0.31 for now. On a real iPhone it behaves even worse. Thanks for sharing